# Process Builder without Matching Conditions?

Tags: process-builder

Hi I have a process builder that is triggered when a platform event is inserted.  It's mainly used as a middle man between the event getting inserted and launching a flow.  So all it really does is read the platform event and pass the event references to the flow.  The only thing is I don't really see a way to have no Matching conditions.  There isn't a need to lookup any records for this action but I'm having to stick one in there.  Is there a workaround to not lookup the matching conditions?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "matching conditions"? That terminology does not match with any feature in `Process Builder`. Perhaps add a screen shot so it is clear and explicit what you are referring to.

Comment: So under the first block inside the process builder "When to Start the Process".  Just added a screenshot.

Comment: I guess they are different for Platform Events.

Comment: May be just add CreatedDate OR CreatedById not null check?